# Recurrence relation of degree 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

i have got this recurrence relation : $$ g(n)+5g(n-1)-6g(n-2) = 14-2^n\cdot2 $$
so far I have figured out the characteristic polynomial: $ x^2+5x-6 = 0 $ this factors to $ (x+6)(x-1)=0$ so my homogenous solution is $$g(n)= C_1+ (-6)^nC_2$$

Now, how do I deal with this error function? $$f(h) = -2^n\cdot 2 +14$$
I tried plugging in $$An(-2)^n\cdot 2+Bn$$ to obtain the particular solution, but this led to nonsense.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: $h(n)=14-2\cdot 2^n$ is a solution to $h(n)-3h(n-1)+2h(n-2)=0,$ with $h(0)=12, h(1)=10.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $g(m)=h(m)+Am+B+C2^m$

$$14-2\cdot2^n$$
$$=h(n)+An+B+C2^n+5(h(n-1)+An-A+B+C2^{n-1})-6\{h(n-2)+An-2A+B+C2^{n-2}\}$$

$$=h(n)+5h(n-1)-6h(n-2)+7A+C2^{n-2}(4+10-6)$$

Set $7A=14\implies A=?$

and $C2^{n-2}(4+10-6)=-2\cdot2^n\implies C=-1$

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can you elaborate on how you came up with $g(m)$In in the first line?

Comment: @philippnirnberger,  More generally we can choose $$g(m)=h(m)+A2^n+b_0+b_1m+b_2m^2+\cdots$$   As the right hand side has a constant $(14), b_r=0$ for $\ge2$  Also, for $-2\cdot2^{n+1},$ it has to be $C2^n$